# self.frame returning different values

Tags: objective-c, swift, size, frame

I'm converting code from objective c to swift. I'm using self.frame to detect frame size. I'm testing on an iPhone 6 simulator. The following objective c code returns self.frame as 0, 0, 375, 667. However the swift code returns self.frame as(0.0,0.0,1024.0,768.0). What is causing this difference?

```
CGFloat yDiv = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)/5.0;
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
```

Objective C code logs {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}

In Swift

```
 var yDiv:CGFloat = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)/5.0
 println("\(self.frame)")
```

Swift code prints out (0.0,0.0,1024.0,768.0) to console.

Comment: For some reason swift is returning iPad 2 dimensions instead of iPhone 6

Answer (score 1):

The above happened because I was using the iOS "Game" template that comes with Xcode. I had to alter the code in the viewController to set the proper bounds

```
let scene:SKScene = GameScene.init(size: skView.bounds.size)
```

Hope this helps others.